# Ambient Enum Declaration Error

Tags: javascript, angular

Whenever I run my Angular 4 app that calls an enum like this one...

```
export declare enum RemoteStatus {
    REMOTE = "REMOTE",
    ACTIVATING = "ACTIVATING",
    ACTIVE = "ACTIVE",
    DEACTIVATING = "DEACTIVATING",
    INACTIVE = "INACTIVE",
}
export declare enum Status {
    UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN",
    LOCKED = "LOCKED",
    UNLOCKED = "UNLOCKED",
}
```

It gives me an error on the ng serve console.

```
ERROR in D:/Projects/nem-swiftbc-app/node_modules/nem-library/dist/src/models/account/AccountInfo.d.ts (4,14): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.

ERROR in D:/Projects/nem-swiftbc-app/node_modules/nem-library/dist/src/models/account/AccountInfo.d.ts (5,18): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
```

This prevents the app from loading. Any clue as to how can this be resolved?

Comment: Can you remove `declare` and try again? and remove the last commas?

Comment: @echonax tried removing the declare but it didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: which TS version you are using? Have you tried to upgrade it ?

Comment: That's the first thing I did (update TS version). It didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolved this by updating my typescript version.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```